# Retrieve the time it took for spark to finish the job

Tags: apache-spark

I need to time some things in spark, e.g. how long it takes for spark to read my file, so I like to use `sc.setLogLevel("INFO")` to enable extra information printed to the screen and one thing I find really useful is when a message like this is printed
`2018-12-18 02:05:38 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 2 finished: count at <console>:26, took 9.555080 s` because this tells me how long something took.

Is there anyway to get this programmatically (preferably in scala) ? Right now I just copy this result and save it in a text file.

Comment: You can track all the progress with SparkListener, which is already used in Spark UI. You can take a look at the SparkListener.scala. I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class TimedResult[R](result: R, durationInNanoSeconds: FiniteDuration)

  def time[R](block: => R): TimedResult[R] = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    val duration = t1 - t0
    TimedResult(result, duration nanoseconds)
  }
```

and then use it call your code block :

```
val timedResult = time{
 someDataframe.count()
}

println("Count of records ${timedResult.result}")

println("Time taken : ${timedResult.durationInNanoSeconds.toSeconds}")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions available to record logging for your spark program.

a) You can redirect your console output to a desired file while using the spark-submit command.

```
spark-submit your_code_file > logfile.txt 2>&1
```

b) There are 2 log files (log4j.properties) can be created for driver and executor and while issuing the spark-submit command include them by giving their path in java options for driver and executer.

```
spark-submit --class MAIN_CLASS --driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:LOG4J_PATH" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:LOG4J_PATH" --master MASTER_IP:PORT JAR_PATH
```

Comment: I'm planning to write a script where I will be timing several different operations. If I simply redirect the log to a file, it will be painful to parse it correctly afterwards - to find the time for the first task, I will have to find the first instance of `02:05:38 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 2 finished: count at <console>:26, took 9.555080 s`, for 99th task - 99th occurrence of `02:05:38 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Job 2 finished: count at <console>:26, took 9.555080 s`. This solution is not ideal, that is why I asked for a way to get this programmatically.